# How to call a method from layout with variables

Tags: java, android, xml, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I may be going about this the wrong way - applying what I know from other API's - so, if so, perhaps you can point me in a different direction.  The fact is, I can't seem to find any examples for exactly what I am doing. I'm trying to call a method from the xml layout.  I want to call the same method from various checkboxes, basically on a click of any checkbox, I want to store the isChecked state in the SharedPreferences file.  This is my xml and java:

```
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="194dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Chri"
        android:id="@+id/chkbxChristmas"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="savePreferencesData(@string/Chri,@+id/chkbxChristmas)"/>


public void savePreferencesData(String preference,int id) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(id);
    editor.putBoolean(preference, cb1.isChecked());

    // Commit the edits!
    editor.commit();

    };
```

As you can see, I'm trying to pass the checkbox ID and the @string/Chri string value (I use this value as the tag in the SharedPreferences file) so the method knows which preference to update.

Is it even possible to pass the variables, and is there a better way to identify which checkbox is calling the method?

I appreciate the help!

Just a quick update:  For some reason I could not get the Lister to function... here is my code:

```
public void saveHanuPref(View view) {
    final CheckBox checkBox = ( CheckBox ) findViewById( R.id.chkbxHanukkah );
   checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new  CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
       {
           if ( isChecked )
           {
               SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
               editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.Hanu), checkBox.isChecked());
               editor.commit();
           }
       }
   });
}
```

Calling this simple method from the activity xml (using onClick) did work:

```
  public void saveChriPref(View view) {
    CheckBox checkBox = ( CheckBox ) findViewById( R.id.chkbxChristmas );
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.Chri), checkBox.isChecked());
    editor.commit();
  };
```

Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The method you declare in your `onClick()` method of the button can take only one input type - it is the View which holds that button. No other data can be specified.
2. Said that, the method in onCLick should be only the name of the method, no parameters etc.

   android:onClick = "savePreferencesData()"
3. Assuming, you are using the `Activity` class, this is how the method should be created.

   public void savePreferencesData(View v) {
       // do what you want
   }
4. The method you declared in the xml file should be present in the same Activity class only. Said that, other buttons in other XML files cannot re-use this method.

> is there a better way to identify which checkbox is calling the
>   method?

Try the below code sample:

```
YOUR_CHECKBOX_NAME.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(YOUR_CHECKBOX_NAME.isChecked()) {
            System.out.println("Checked");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Un-Checked");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That seems to add  a lot of code if you have a bunch of checkboxes, but sounds like that's how its done.  Thanks for the detailed post.

Answer (score 2):

The right way would be to set an `OnCheckedChangeListener`

```
CheckBox checkBox = ( CheckBox ) findViewById( R.id.chkbxChristmas );
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            // perform logic
        }

    }
});
```